# Database Access in R: MariaDB vs RODBC, dplyr etc

Tags: r, database, ms-access, mariadb

I'm a noob so forgive my ignorance :-)

I'm creating a Shiny app to perform read/write operations on an existing MS Access database (.mdb) with about 20 small tables and a variety of joins on them. I may have a small number of people connecting simultaneously.

I have planned to use MariaDB (RMariaDB). I notice e.g. RODBC  or dplyr can connect to .mdb directly? The app will be hosted on a remote server.

It's unlikely the largest table will exceed 5000 rows in the next 2 years. Should I be using MariaDB now or would the other 'direct' options be enough?

Many thanks in advance for your replies...

Gary

Comment: What database you use is really a matter of personal preference. It's not clear how decides what you *should* be using. This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you try one solution and have a particular technical question, then maybe ask here.

Comment: MrFlick I appreciate your points. Yes, it is a general question but where does a noob go for advice to get started? Anyhow, understood. Tx anyway...

Comment: Where does one get started is also not an appropriate question here, unfortunately. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We don't allow opinion-based questions nor questions about off-site resources. Best try RStudio community or another R-specific community if you want to follow a random internet persons preference. We answer clearly-defined questions  with objective answers here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to 'which db shall I use?', but it is a recommendation for a starting point:

https://db.rstudio.com/

The short answer is 'ensure DBI compatibility' and the slightly longer answer is 'for Shiny apps consider using the pool package'.